# Slide toggle on submit

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm thinking about how my code would work.

I want to slide toggle a div or span when I'm hovering an input submit. Like this :

[image]

How can I do that ? Should I  create a span before submit button

Or

Should I add content with `.submit:before`

Comment: Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like this? You can do it without JavaScript.

```css
button {text-decoration: none; background-color: #99f; color: #fff; font-family: Segoe UI; display: inline-block; border: 0; padding: 0; cursor: pointer;}
button span {display: inline-block; -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease; -o-transition: all 0.5s ease; transition: all 0.5s ease; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px 2px;}
button span:first-child {width: 0; padding: 10px 0; overflow: hidden; background-color: #999;}
button:hover span:first-child {width: 25px; padding: 10px 0 10px 10px;}
```

```html
<button type="submit">
  <span>Go</span><span>Submit</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Yes exactly, but the button is an input submit, not a link

Comment: @CorentinBranquet Updated with `<button />`

Answer (score 0):

You should use some css and transition.

HTML

```
<div class="element">
  <span>Go!</span>
  Send
</div>
```

CSS

```
.element:hover {
  span {
    width: 50px;
  }
}
```